# the child class always have access to the public members of its parent, why and how it is possible?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

why does a child class have access to members of a parent class?
and why parent class cannot access the members of child class?
I was preparing for my exams and saw this reasoning question in one of my past papers. this seems quite vague to me , I was confused what will be the proper answer to this question.
it will be quite helpful, if anyone of you guys can provide proper explanation that why parent has no knowledge about child class.

```
class parent{
 public :
 void access(){}
 };
class child:public parent{
 };`
```

Comment: Because that's how it is defined to work? And how would a base class be able to access something from a derived class when it doesn't know which derived class it is?

Comment: if you have `virtual` methods, then parent can access child.

Comment: What makes you think it should not?? [Edit] your question and elaborate about your thoughts please. _"and why parent class cannot access the members of child class?"_ because you didn't introduce `virtual methods.

Comment: Are you cheating on an interview exam?

Comment: In inheritance, an instance of a `child` is also an instance of a `parent`, so it has everything that a `parent` has (though, it might not have *access* to everything). As such, a `child` object can be used wherever a `parent` object can be used.  On the other hand, a `parent` object has no idea whether it is part of a `child` object or not.

Comment: A parent class has no idea how many child classes are spawned.  A child class knows who its parent is.

Comment: The terms Parent and Child don't lend themselves well to discussions of inheritance because inheritance is an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a), and that means Child is a Parent. Weird.

Comment: *"why does a child class have access to members of a parent class?"* -- I thought that was the major point of using inheritance. What is your understanding of inheritance?

Comment: *"this seems quite vague to me"* -- I agree. Quite vague, so unsuitable for both Stack Overflow and (probably) the paper you pulled it from.

Comment: *"it will be quite helpful, if anyone of you guys can provide proper explanation that why parent has no knowledge about child class."* -- it appears you would like to refocus your question on this aspect. If so, I suggest a complete re-write. Currently, your title and opening sentence (the places of most prominence) ask a different question. The part about the base class not knowing its derived classes currently appears to be thrown on as an afterthought, something that could be disregarded in favor of the more prominently-placed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using public inheritance, your derived class will have access to protected and public fields and methods declared in the base class. However, your base class doesn't know about your derived class at all. Inheritance only works one way. You basically extend the functionality of a class.

You can think of it as putting a smaller box into a larger one. Each box knows what's inside it, but it doesn't know what's outside of it. The base class is the smaller box, the derived one is the larger box.